# How can I maximize the space my control occupies while maintaining horizontal order?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have the following linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/SearchBox">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Search: "
            android:id="@+id/SearchText"/>


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_le="@+id/SearchBox"
            />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:id="@+id/SearchButton"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the EditText is between the view and the button. Is there any property I can set that makes the edit text fill the space between the other two controls? (Which have a fixed size, based on their static content).

Setting the Edit Text's layout width to "Fill_parent" pushes off the button (since there's no more room in the parent).

Ideally, I guess the thing to do would be to add the edit text last, specify that it should be between the other two controls, and then set it to fill width.

But I'm not sure how to do that. Any help?

Comment: check padding property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use property `android:weight='1'` on the `EditText` once you have fixed the widths of the other views

Comment: `android:layout_weight`, not `android:weight`